# Identifying a given sequence within a key of python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to recognize if the relevant sequence exists within any key-value pair, and also how to identify the correct key which including the sequence, and what are the conditions that bring to implement it and print in a python code.
Here I am adding the sequence for your reference which I want to identify sequence is `0,1,2,3`

```
mydir = {
    "p1":[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3],  #not includes the relavent sequence 
    "p2":[0,0,1,2,3,4,5],    #includes the relavent sequence
    "p3":[0,1]               #not includes the relavent sequence   
}

if(#condition for identify p2 as a correct key):
   print(#p2 Identified!)
else:
   print("Not Identified!")
```

Comment: Why you are using both `python2` and `python3` tag? Is it because you want to know answer for both python2 and python3?

Comment: You may looking for a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) to implement. If your sequence's first element matches the one you are looping over at the time, you check if the next one is a match untill either your sequence is found, or there is a difference between your sequence and the next element. I'm sure there is a more pythonic way to do it, but it helps you to understand what happens exactly while looking for sequences.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could write a custom function that iterates through the dictionary and creates "sub-sequences" of the same length as the sequence. Then return all the keys where a match is found:

```
def check_sequence(s, d):
    keys = list()
    for k in d:
        sublists = [d[k][i:i+len(s)] for i in range(len(d[k])-4)]
        if s in sublists:
            keys += [k]
    return keys
>>> check_sequence([0, 1, 2, 3], mydir)
['p2']
```

Comment: What about `[0, 12, 34]`?